# Gnome terminal command to .sh script

Tags: bash, script

In gnome terminal this work but

```
$ proxychains firefox 2> pipe.txt
```

I can not make it work from .sh script

```
gnome_terminal --tab -e "proxychains firefox 2> pipe.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the `gnome-terminal` man page, it looks like the command string is executed directly, without invoking `sh` or `bash` so that the I/O redirection would not be supported. Both shells support a `-c` option which should do what you want. Try this:

```
gnome_terminal --tab -e "sh -c 'proxychains firefox 2> pipe.txt'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the guy but... you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't even need to explicitly tell it to run in gnome terminal, and your GUI terminal emulator front end shouldn't matter at all.

Your script should look like

```
#!/bin/bash
proxychains firefox 2> pipe.txt
```

Save it as whatever.sh, make sure its executable.

Then run it in whatever terminal emulator you want, gnome, konsole or retroterm.